# Linear Algebra: Homogeneous system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

How do I go about solving this problem? I have tried part (a) but I'm unable to use the 3 equations that I got to solve part (b). Should I consider cases whereby λ=0 and λ≠0? Or should I rearrange the rows to avoid this altogether? I tried the latter but I still could not avoid the cases.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I would like to know if you have tried part a…It seems trivial if you apply definiton of matrix multiplication

Comment: Yes, i've tried part (a) but I'm not able to solve part (b) using the equation i get in part (a), so I'm not sure if i did it correctly.

Comment: OK but I think part B is a bit strange…since nature of solution set depends on value of lambda

Answer (score 5):

a) Apply matrix multiplication to get the following system

$\begin{cases}x-2y=\lambda x\\
3y+3z=\lambda y\\
x+y+3z=\lambda z\end{cases}$.

Rewrite it as

$\begin{cases}(1-\lambda)x-2y=0\\
(3-\lambda)y+3z=0\\
x+y+(3-\lambda)z=0\end{cases}$.

This is the homogeneous system that you are looking for.

b) The determinant of the coefficient matrix is $\lambda^{3}-7\lambda^{2}+12\lambda$. This has zeros $\lambda=0,3,4$. So if $\lambda\neq 0,3,4$, the coefficient matrix is invertible, hence the system only has the solution $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$.

If $\lambda=0$, you should get by Gauss elimination that the solution is $\{(2y,y,-y): y\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

If $\lambda=3$, get by Gauss elimination the solution $\{(x,-x,0): x\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

If $\lambda=4$, then the solution is $\{(-2z,3z,z): z\in\mathbb{R}\}$.